Microsoft Intune dynamic group. Using -Match to find devices with two Identical special chars
I need to create a dynamic group in Microsoft Intune. I'm looking to use the -match operator to locate the devices I'm trying to add. The name must have two dashes, "-". i.e.
Mov-800-03 would be included.
I did use the following expression "--$*"

It is that you want to match input that contains exactly 2 dashes, not together and not at either end? If so, ^[^-]+-[^-]+-[^-]+$

The following did work for me. It only check for one "-", but that did include all the devices I need:
(device.displayName -match "[a-z]{2,}[-]" )

Thanks for all your help ;)
